# How to make sub-routes with prefix but can work without prefix in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, locale, multilingual

I'm building a multilingual Website using Laravel but I'm facing a problem about Locales.

I have 2 Languages for now (Ar/En) and my routes accept prefix to determine the Language.

I want my routes to be valid if not having a prefix and set a default Locale.

my current code is :

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '/{locale?}',
    'where' => ['locale' => '^(ar|en)$'],
    'middleware' => ['setLocale']
], function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    });

    Route::get('test', function (){
        return 'test';
    });
});
```

It works for the first route but for any sub-routes its not working if prefix is not provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a [fallback route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes)

```php
Route::fallback(function () {
    abort_if(in_array(request()->segment(1), ['ar', 'en']), 404);

    return redirect()->to(url(app()->getLocale().request()->getPathInfo()));
});
```